# Variables returning undefined when defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
    case 'sinfo':
    const sinfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addField('Server Name  :', message.guild.name)
    .setTitle('Server Information ')
    .addField('Server Owner  :', message.guild.owner.user.tag)
    .addField('Members  :', message.guild.memberCount)
    .addField('Text Channels  :', textChannels)
    .addField('Voice Channels  :', voiceChannels)
    .addField('All channels', channels)
    .addField('Roles', roless)
    .addField('Region :', 'Czech Republic')
    .addField('Created At :', 'Sat Jan 27 2018 12:04:06')
    .setFooter('For more commands check text channel :grey_exclamation:commands:grey_exclamation:')
    .setColor(0xF8F8F8)
    .setThumbnail(message.guild.displayAvatarURL)
    var channels = message.guild.channels.cache.length
    var roless = message.guild.roles.cache.length
    var textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text").length
    var voiceChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "voice").length
    message.channel.send(sinfo);
```

in actual discord embed there arent numbers just `undefined`.

Comment: Always keep questions separate, you need to write a new question regarding the server region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact that you defined the roles under the embed, move them above the embed:

```js
case 'sinfo': 

var channels = message.guild.channels.cache.size
var roless = message.guild.roles.cache.size
var textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text").size 
var voiceChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "voice").size

const sinfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.addField('Server Name :', message.guild.name) 
.setTitle('Server Information ') 
.addField('Server Owner :', message.guild.owner.user.tag)
.addField('Members :', message.guild.memberCount) 
.addField('Text Channels :', textChannels) 
.addField('Voice Channels :', voiceChannels) 
.addField('All channels', channels) 
.addField('Roles', roless) 
.addField('Region :', 'Czech Republic') 
.addField('Created At :', 'Sat Jan 27 2018 12:04:06') 
.setFooter('For more commands check text channel :grey_exclamation:commands:grey_exclamation:') 
.setColor(0xF8F8F8) 
.setThumbnail(message.guild.displayAvatarURL) 

 message.channel.send(sinfo);
```

Comment: I have tried and still undefined, I think there is something wrong with the vars..@Syntle